# Dialog box does not show CListBox Contents when called with DoModal

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I am trying to initialize a CDialog box, which contains a CListBox. I want to do this by calling DoModal on the CDialogBox. However the problem is that when I call DoModal, the dialog box opens, but the CListBox is EMPTY. (its items were already initialized)
When I call ShowWindow(SW_SHOW), the Dialog box does show up also, and the CListBox contains the items I inserted into it. However, I do not want to use this method since it does not pause execution of the program. (DoModal pauses program execution until window is closed)

**So my question is: How can I open the dialog box using DoModal, AND have the CListBox show its contents?**
Thanks a lot.

Initializing the CDialog subclass, and calling start (which opens the dialog box)

```
loadNewWorld = new LoadNewWorld(this);
loadNewWorld->Create(IDD_LOAD_NEW_WORLD , this);
loadNewWorld->Start();
```

LoadNewWorld class:

```
//Constructor header
LoadNewWorld::LoadNewWorld(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/) : CDialog(LoadNewWorld::IDD, pParent)

//This shows the dialog box, but does NOT show the items in CListBox
    void LoadNewWorld::Start ()
    {
        populateList();
        DoModal();
    }

//This shows the dialog box AND shows the populated CListBox. However, don't want to do this way
    void LoadNewWorld::Start ()
    {
        populateList();
        ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    }
```

Comment: Dialogs can be created modeless (using `Create`) or modally (using `DoModal`). These methods cannot be mixed. Also, if you are going to use `DoModal` then the filling of the listbox must be done within its `OnInitDialog` handler ie. After the dialog box and listbox windows have been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate the list view when the Dialog starts up and is created.

You can not populate the list box when the Dialog isn't created. The best place to do this is OnInitDialog. Your Problem is that you want to populate the list box before it is created (before the call to DoModal).

As the note already told you: You can not mix DoModal and Create.